# Will python wait for all threads to finish before exiting?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading

I have the below python script:

**script.py**

```
from threading import Thread

def func():
    while True:
        pass

a = Thread(target=func)
a.start()

print('started the thread')
```

When running it from the terminal (`python script.py`), it prints `started the thread` and hangs in there. Coming from the `C` background I know when the main thread completes the remaining threads are terminated as well. Is that not the case in Python? Will the python wait even without a call to `a.join()`? Is there a concept of main thread in python or all threads are same?

Comment: You can test it yourself if you put a print inside the while-loop. Does it continue printing or does it stop after `'started the thread'` has been printed?

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Sometimes it is good to know the reasons behind a behavior than to just know the language features :) Anyways, are all threads the same? There is nothing like a special main thread as in C whose termination will terminate rest of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "main thread" in Python, which is generally the thread that started the Python interpreter. Threads created by the `threading` module have some layers of behavior on top of native OS threads. One of those behaviors is that when the interpreter exits, part of normal shutdown processing is that the main thread joins each non-daemon `threading.Thread` - so, yes, Python normally waits for all other threads to end.

Whether daemon `threading.Thread`s are forcefully shut down when Python exits is up to the OS, although I believe all major operating systems now do kill them.

If you want to exit the interpreter regardless of whether non-daemon `threading.Thread`s are running, you need to kill the job, or call `os._exit()`. Note the leading underscore! It's not recommended, but is there if you need it.

Comment: Does the default execution (code that doesn't run in spawned threads) happen in the same thread python interpreter is started ("main thread") or interpreter creates a new thread for execution?

Comment: If you (or module facilities you invoke) never create another thread, the main thread is the only thread that will ever exist. So, "yes" to the first part of your question, to the extent I understand it. CPython never creates a thread all on its own.